# How to convert string to date "141104" with 2014 year?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have string , and want to convert to date.

The problem is when convert (for example)  `"141104"` ==>  it will be `"04/11/0014"` 
How I will solve year `0014` to be `2014`?

I used :

```
DateTime EntranceDeclaratioDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(outputDueNo.ThirdPart.Substring(0, 2)), int.Parse(outputDueNo.ThirdPart.Substring(2, 2)), int.Parse(outputDueNo.ThirdPart.Substring(4, 2)));
```

Comment: [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Because [`DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes **exact** year as a first parameter. Not two-digit representation of it.

That's why your code equivalent to

```
new DateTime(14, 11, 04);
```

not

```
new DateTime(2014, 11, 04);
```

*Generally*, splitting your string and using these parts in a `DateTime` constructor is not a good idea. At least I don't like it.

You can use custom date and time format parsing if `yyMMdd` is not a standard date and time format of your culture like;

```
string s = "141104";
DateTime EntranceDeclaratioDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out EntranceDeclaratioDate))
{
    // Successfull parsing, now EntranceDeclaratioDate is 04/11/2014 00:00:00
}
```

[The `"yy"` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yySpecifier) represents the year as a two-digit number. And this specifier based on [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx) of your current calendar which is [Gregorian Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) in my example since I used [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach, the year could be corrected by an addition as follows.

```
 DateTime EntranceDeclaratioDate
   = new DateTime(int.Parse(outputDueNo.ThirdPart.Substring(0, 2)) + 2000,
                  int.Parse(outputDueNo.ThirdPart.Substring(2, 2)),
                  int.Parse(outputDueNo.ThirdPart.Substring(4, 2)));
```

However, I strongly second the comment above and recommend usage of the `DateTime.Parse` method.

Comment: This string has no starting index as `18`.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, but the same indexing is used in the original question.

Comment: No, it will not work. Using your approach, how do you express the year 1914?

Answer (score 0):

```
string outputDueNo = "141104";
char[] st = new char[6];
st=outputDueNo.ToCharArray();

string date = st[4].ToString() + st[5].ToString() + "/" + st[2].ToString() + st[3].ToString() + "/" + "20" + st[0].ToString() + st[1].ToString();      
DateTime ds = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: Your `char` array is totally unnecessary. You can declare a character as `st[4]` without to create this `st` array. And there is no guarantee OP's `CurrentCulture` to parse your `date` string. Sorry but this is a bad way to solve this problem.